# Visually impaired friend wants to try Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, accessibility

I've got a friend who is using Windows 7 and I "sold" him the benefits of open source, and he actually wants to try Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (that's the good news)! The bad news are: he is visually impaired and he has some problems with his hands/fingers.

Are there some packages that can help visually impaired people?

Like a zoom shortcuts with his mouse … I don't know … And also packages that can write with voices? He uses accessibility stuff in his phone doing that, so it might be good on his PC as well.

Comment: I would suggest you to post your queries as separate questions, it's very difficult to discuss so many issues in a single Q&A. Also if I'm not mistaken Ubuntu comes with many accessibility options and applications like screen reader, screen magnification, large texts, high contrast, on screen keyboard, typing assist, mouse click assist, mouse double click delay etc.

Comment: Do you think it is really necessary to post multiple questions? I mean they're that big no? (I'm sorry if I go against the rules)

Comment: Nope it is not, he still has vision but he struggle seeing little things.

Comment: @Didan974 Are you sure none of the information in the answers to [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787469/what-is-the-ubuntu-accessibility-for-blind-people) answers this? Although the title does say "for blind people," *much* of the information in the answers is about magnification, increasing contrast, and so forth.

Comment: @Didan974 and OP of that post also mentions "partially blind". While it might be PC and all to say visually impaired, "blind" is still simpler and easily understood everywhere.

Comment: Okay I got it. Do I have to delete my question?

Comment: No, you certainly don't have to delete your question, and since it has an upvoted and accepted answer the system will probably not allow you to do that. Closing a question as a duplicate doesn't imply it's not useful; the purpose of doing so is to link and gather resources for the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is software already installed in Ubuntu dealing with accessibility under *Universal Access* in Settings. Check out **Visual Impairments** in https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y.html

[image]